# how to export (fabric) canvas objects to pdf

Tags: php, fabricjs

I'm creating an image editing application, I want to generate a pdf from fabric JavaScript linked HTML canvas, I can also use PHP, the approach inside my mind is, exporting as a JSON and taking from PHP then converting to PDF, but I'm not able to export JSON from canvas right now, can anybody guide me ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KJ for my implementation  I am planning to add  AJAX to get Objects from canvas using `JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON());` Method And then i will try some Php to pdf Creating method. is this right way ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this demo I wrote showing how to export fabric to pdf
http://fabricjs.com/import-pdf

In general it is good to get to know [fabric demos](http://fabricjs.com/demos/)

I would remove the the word `html` from the title as it is misleading

Comment: Ya as per your guideline, i have checked some of demos, I also tried [blob] method to pass this object `JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON());` I will try this and update you shortly

Comment: Meanwhile and by chance I came across [canvas2pdf](https://github.com/joshua-gould/canvas2pdf) which looks awesome. I want to support it from within fabric. But it must wait since we have more pressing issues.